# OpenApiSpecification JSON inside of another JSON

Tags: json, openapi

Hey guys I'm trying to create OAS3 200 response which returns JSON inside of JSON. The problem is I simply don't know what syntax I should use here. I tried to make a double reference but I don't know if it's possible to do that way.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "messageType": "error",
    "error": {
        "apiKey": "apiKey must not be empty"
    }
}


  responses:
    '200':
      description: Upon successful generated invoice you will be returned with the following JSON.
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
              oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/success'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/invalid'
```

---

```
components:
  schemas:
    invalid:
      type: object
      properties:
        success:
          description: Says if the invoice was generated successfully.
          type: boolean
          example: false
        messageType:
          description: Type of the message
          type: string
          example: error
        error:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/def/data'
def:
  data:
    type: object
    properties:
      apikey:
        description: lol
        type: string
        example: lolol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Define your `data` schema in `components/schemas`, and make the `error` property a `$ref` to this schema.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    invalid:
      type: object
      properties:
        success:
          ...
        messageType:
          ...
        error:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/data'  # <--------

    data:  # <--------
      type: object
      properties:
        apikey:
          description: lol
          type: string
          example: lolol
```

Another way is to define the nested schema inline:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    invalid:
      type: object
      properties:
        success:
          ...
        messageType:
          ...
        error:
          type: object   # <--------
          properties:
            apikey:
              description: lol
              type: string
              example: lolol
```